# My watchOS 3 app is not recognizing the entitlements file that authorizes HealthKit in my watch extension folder

Tags: ios

I'm working on a watchOS 3 health app, but neither the simulator nor my actual apple watch devices are recognizing the entitlements file that is present in my extensions folder this is making me get this error :

workout session did fail with error: Error Domain=com.apple.healthkit Code=4 "Missing com.apple.developer.healthkit entitlement." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Missing com.apple.developer.healthkit entitlement.}

what do I need to do in order to correct this?

PLEASE NOTE: I have already turned the healthkit button on in the capabilities tab.

Answer (score 0):

I found out I wasn't enabling it on watch under the capabilities for the watch specifically. I had only done it for iOS not watchOS